# How do I still read an RSS with a missing xml header tag?

Tags: c#, xml, rss

I am using C#'s xmlTextReader to parse an RSS xml file. It works fine except when there is a missing header tag. How do I get around this issue without injecting the header myself?

Comment: what's the error message that you're getting?

Comment: How does your failing code look like?

Comment: The error (Exception message) is: Unexpected node type Element. ReadElementString method can only be called on elements with simple or empty content

Comment: @Phil: don't use `XmlTextReader` unless you're stuck with .NET 1.1. It's been deprecated since .NET 2.0. Use `XmlReader.Create` instead.

Comment: @John Saunders. I have legacy code that uses XmlTextReader.

Comment: @Phil: then change it as soon as you can, and stop using it for new development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got around this by implementing [Peter Bromberg's](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/tutorials/aspnet/9faa101f-0a1a-465f-a41a-3e52dd9f7526/everything-rss--atom-feed-parser.aspx) custom RSS reader. It is more work compared to using Microsoft's inbuilt reader, however, you can tweak Bromberg's reader to handle errors in the RSS feed with ease.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `XmlTextReader.Settings.ConformanceLevel` property set to `ConformanceLevel.Fragment`. But that will relax some other validation checks.

Comment: Given that it is already missing a header tag I doubt that relaxed validation is really a big issue.